# Is there a name for the following random process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random, random-walk

I have a random process which seems to oscillate between extremes in terms of trending but which is locally like a Brownian motion or a fractional Brownian motion.

[image: Random Process]

Is there a name for such a random/stochastic process?

Answer (score 1):

Looks an awful like a version of a [jump-diffusion process](http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/jgatheral/JumpDiffusionModels.pdf), especially since its brownian between oscillations.

Comment: The Merton Jump Diffusion Process is discussed here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MertonsJumpDiffusionModel/ but the main difference is that between jumps, the signal seems to be much more oscillating and controlled, almost white noise...

Comment: @user13675 you didn't really give much data on your process. I don't know if its specifically a Merton jump diffusion, but it appears to be in the class of jump diffusions. I doubt you'll find a named process that exactly matches your graph, typically you look for a class of models.